# I am trying to split using Regex

Tags: python, regex

Below is the snippet i used :

```
test= "CAT 13.589 ± 24.5 CAT 55  +/- 24"
       
ResSearch = re.findall(r'CAT\s?\d+?\s?\.?d?\d?\d?\d?\s?[± +/-]\s?\d+\.?\d?\d?\d?',text)

str1 = ''.join(ResSearch)

if ResSearch:

 ts=str1.split("±")

 print(ts)
```

Expected Output is:

```
13.589 24.5
55   24
```

Comment: please provide your text input

Comment: she wants to catch the input in test

Comment: @DavidMeu test= "CAT 13.589 ± 24.5 CAT 55 +/- 24" is the text input

Comment: Can't you just split on `\s+(?=CAT\b)` for example?

Comment: @DavidMeu The expected output is 13.589 24.5 and 
 55   24

Comment: @JvdV I want to fetch only those number seperately and have to pass them to respective dataframe seperately. The expected output is 13.589 24.5 and 55 24

Comment: @GayathriKumar, I think it's wise to reflect this in your OP as not everyone will read comments and your expected output does not match what you wrote earlier.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `pandas`, `numpy`, and `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re
z=[]
test= "CAT 13.589 ± 24.5 CAT 55  +/- 24"
regex=re.compile(r'CAT\s?\d+?\s?\.?d?\d?\d?\d?\s?[± +/-]+\s?\d+\.?\d?\d?\d?')
l=regex.findall(test)
if l!=[]:
   for i in l:
      if '±' in i:
         z=i.split('±')
         num=z[0][4:]
         print(num,z[1])
      else:
         z=i.split('+/-')
         num=z[0][4:]
         print(num,z[1])
```

**the out put will be**

```
13.589 24.5
55 24
```

i not understood what you are trying to do so i just concentrated providing you desired output ..i think when you use `±` as parameter to split it will not included in output list

Note : im new to python so i tried using my basic knowledge

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to get only those numbers seperately. Like 13.589    24.5 and 55    24 . Have to remove CAT and the symbols

Comment: i got it...use `[± +/-]+` in Regular expression

Comment: I have to get rid of the word CAT as well as the symbols

Comment: i will try to remove CAT now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the numbers only then you can use the following:

```py
import re
test= "CAT 13.589 ± 24.5 CAT 55  +/- 24"
regex=re.compile(r'CAT\s*([-\d.]+)\s*[±+/-]+\s*([\d.]+)')
print(regex.findall(test))
```

The output:

```
[('13.589', '24.5'), ('55', '24')]
```

I also included the minus in the first regex to find the number, because I suppose it might be possible that the first number is negative. If you are sure that both numbers are positive you can replace `[-\d.]` with `[\d.]`.